# Find $\lim_\limits{x\to 0}\frac{1-(\cos x)^{\sin x}}{x}$ using little o

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, functions

$\lim_\limits{x\to 0}\frac{1-e^{\sin(x) \ln(\cos x)}}{x}=\lim_\limits{x\to 0}\frac{1-e^{(x+o(x))\ln(1-\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2))}}{x}=\lim_\limits{x\to0}\frac{1-e^{(x+o(x))(-\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2))}}{x}$. If this is correct, what will happen with $o()$ after multiplication? Will it be $o(x),o(x^2)$ or $o(x^3)$ and how to finish it afterwards?

---

I am solving this problem using this method because the question asks me to do so.

Comment: It would be $o(x^3)$, which is enough, I think, but note that you can get another degree by recognizing that $\sin x = x + o(x^2)$ and $\cos x = 1-\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^3)$.

Comment: An alternative / easy way is note that since numerator is like $A-B$ where both $A, B$ tend to $1$. Hence it can be replaced by $\log A-\log B$ and this gives the desired limit as $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proceed like this: 
\begin{align}
& \frac{1 - (\cos x)^{\sin x}}{x} \\
= & \frac{1 - \exp(\sin x \ln(\cos x))}{x} \\
= & \frac{1 - \exp\left(\sin x \ln(1 - \frac{1}{2}x^2 + o(x^3))\right)}{x} \quad 
(\text{expand } \cos x)\\
= & \frac{1 - \exp\left(\sin x \times \left(- \frac{1}{2}x^2 + o(x^3)\right)\right)}{x} \quad (\text{expand } \ln(1 + x)) \\
= & \frac{1 - \left[1 + \left(\sin x \times \left(- \frac{1}{2}x^2 + o(x^3)\right)\right) + o(x^4)\right]}{x} \quad (\text{expand } e^x) \\
= & \frac{\frac{1}{2}x^2\sin x + o(x^3)}{x} \\
= & \frac{1}{2}x\sin x + o(x^2) \to 0 
\end{align}
as $x \to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

As $\lim_{x\to 0} \cos{x} \approx 1-\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2)$ and $\sin{x} \approx x+o(x)$.

$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1-{\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2)\right)}^{x+o(x)}}{x}$.

I'd use L'Hôpital's rule for this limit.  After differentiating the numerator and denominator, you're left with:

$\lim_{x\to 0} {\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)}^{x}\cdot\left(-\ln{\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)}+\frac{x^2}{1-\frac{x^2}{2}}\right)=\boxed{0}$